# Dropdown switching subcategories portfolio

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, filters, dropdown

I have portfolio on my site and i want add dropdown switching subcategories for taxanomy 'potfolio-types'

For example:

> Category A
>
> - subcategory 1
> - subcategory 2
> - etc...

when're in category A, the drop-down list shows the child category. When selecting child category, go to her.

I use this code

```
<?php 
$args = array('hide_empty'=>1,'depth'=>1,'hierarchical'=> 0, 'show_count'=> 1,'taxonomy'=> 'portfolio-types',);
?>
<ul>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

But the list shows all the categories and subcategories. And there is no transition.

Comment: Have you looked into the 'child_of' argument?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'child_of' argument lets you select subcategories from a parent category, and a you can get the current taxonomy id to pass as the value:

```
<?php 

$category_id = get_queried_object_id();
$args = array(
    'hide_empty'=>1,
    'depth'=>1,
    'hierarchical'=> 0, 
    'show_count'=> 1,
    'taxonomy'=> 'portfolio-types', 
    'child_of' => $category_id
    );
?>
<ul>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

So in the example above, only children (sub-categories) of portfolio-type of the current category ID will be displayed.

Note that this code will only work if you are in a taxonomy archive page, which I think that's what you intend to do.

Comment: Yes, it`s work. Now I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good to hear. I see that you are new to SO; to mark the question as answered, click the check mark on the left (below the 0 and arrows) of my answer.